# GET simplified data via curl in etcd

Tags: rest, curl, etcd

I am a bit of a noob to curl/REST, and have looked but can't find much that makes sense to me.

am playing with etcd, storing some keys, i can use etcdctl to pull a single return, which is very handy, as I intend to echo such things into config files;

> etcdctl get /dtank/facts/server/IP
>
> 10.2.0.91

which is ace. what I'm trying to do now is get that same functionality via curl, as I will need to make such requests on machines that do not have etcdctl installed.

when I run the following;

> curl -L http://localhost:4001/v2/keys/dtank/facts/server/IP

I get this;

> {"action":"get","node":{"key":"/dtank/facts/server/IP","value":"10.2.0.91","modifiedIndex":19,"createdIndex":19}}

My question here is really, do I need to jump through hoops [grep, sed, etc] to resolve this return down to the IP address, which is what I'm after, or is there some trick I can use to request just *that* value?

many many thanks in advance!

Comment: Would prehaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools help?

Comment: many thanks @Michal, i've found that getting jq installed resolves the issue :)